# Append HTML inner elements to the table using Angular Js

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

this is my html

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="tham" ng-controller="tham-control">
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>`enter code here`
                        <th>Sl.No</th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Cost</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="items">
                        <td><input type="number" ng-model="slno"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number" ng-model="product"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number" ng-model="cost"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number" ng-model="quantity"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number" ng-model="total" value="{{ cost*quantity }}"/></td>
                        <td><button ng-click="add_row()" >Add</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is my angular js and jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script>
    // filter can be added using pipe charcter
    var app = angular.module("tham",[]);
    app.controller("tham-control",function($scope){
        $scope.cost = 0;
        $scope.quantity = 0;
        $scope.total = 0;
        $scope.add_row = function(){
            $this = $(this);
            var html = $this.parents('tr.items').html();
            var  new_html = "<tr class='items'>"+html+"</tr>";
            $this.parents('tbody').append(new_html);
        }
    });
</script>
```

here i wanna do is that, when i click **"Add"** button then i want to append **"tr.items"** row to **"tbody"** tag using Angular Js. Somebody please correct the question if it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. You have to create a datasource for your items, and let angular repeat over it.

```
<div ng-app="tham" ng-controller="ThamController as thc">
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sl.No</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="items" ng-repeat="it in thc.items">
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="it.slno"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="it.product"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" ng-model="it.cost"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" ng-model="it.quantity"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" ng-value="it.cost * it.quantity"/></td>
                    <td><button ng-click="thc.addRow()" ng-show="$last" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("tham", []);

app.controller("ThamController", [function() {
    var _self = this;

    this.items = [];
    this.addRow = function() {
        _self.items.push({
            slno: '',
            product: '',
            cost: 0,
            quantity: 0
        });
    };
    this.addRow();
}]);
```

see a working [example](http://codepen.io/pbaris/pen/qOXGQj?editors=101)

Comment: thanks a lot @pbaris . this is exactly what i want. But i didn't get the logic behind this. l know  jquery and javascript but i am a begginer in angular . So could you please suggest me a good documentation to learn all this stuff.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs and https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs it's a good start

Answer (score 4):

Your just doing the complete opossite of what Angular is supposed.

First of all you have to create a repository of your items, even if that is blank, and after that you should iterate through items and print them :

```js
var app = angular.module("tham", []);
app.controller("tham-control", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = []; //Initialize Repository
  $scope.cost = 0;
  $scope.quantity = 0;
  $scope.add_row = function() {
    //Add item to the repository 
    $scope.items.unshift({
      'slno': $scope.slno,
      'product': $scope.product,
      'cost': $scope.cost,
      'quantity': $scope.quantity
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="tham" ng-controller="tham-control">
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>`enter code here`
            <th>Sl.No</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="items">
            <td>
              <input type="number" ng-model="slno" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" ng-model="product" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" ng-model="cost" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" ng-model="quantity" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" ng-value="cost*quantity" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <button ng-click="add_row()">Add</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- filter can be added using pipe charcter -->
          <tr class="items" ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>
              {{item.slno}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{item.product}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{item.cost}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{item.quantity}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{item.cost*item.quantity }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can refer a complete add edit and delete functionality here.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54475/basic-and-simple-view-add-edit-and-delete-functionality